# putting logo on same line but after title, latex

Tags: diagrams, titles, logos

I read all similar questions and their answers. But as total beginner they are not helping. Hope you can.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{test}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{logo2.jpg}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick hack: place two `minipage`s besides each other

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{test}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\maketitle
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u a lot.Can I somehow move it to right?

Comment: @MaYa To move it right, you can make the first minipage bigger, e.g. `\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}`

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You can just add this to the title.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{test $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-duck}}}$} 
\date{}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to place the picture while keeping the title centered, and want to put it, say, at the right end of the current page's text area, I recommend `tikzpagenodes` along with the `tikzmark` library.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in,showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\title{\tikzmarknode{title}{test}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[anchor=east,inner sep=0pt] at (title-|current page text area.east) {\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}} 
\date{}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

[image]

`showframe` is only used to guide the eye.

Comment: Thank you a lot!